# How to loop over an array and create a new json object using its data based on some keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a list of objects in an array,

```
[
  { "long_name": "1144", "short_name": "1144", "types": ["street_address"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "New York", "types": ["city"] },
  { "long_name": "New York County", "short_name": "New York County", "types": ["admin_area", "portal"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "NY", "types": ["state"] },
  { "long_name": "United States", "short_name": "US", "types": ["country"] }
]
```

what i want to do is create a new object but with different key names. For example the 1st object "1144" will become something like

```
{
  "street_short": 1144,
  "street_long": 1144,
  ...

  // second object will become like
  "city_short": "New York",
  "city_long": "New York",
}
```

This should be done based on the type of the object. As in the above example, the type was "street_address", so the new json became "street_short" and "street_long". Basically it should be based on what the type is.

I tried doing it with Lodash but no success:

```
var getAddressFromGooglePlace = function(address) {
  let newObj = {};
  if (!address) {
    return;
  }
  if (!address.address_components || !address.address_components.length) {
    return;
  }

  let findInArray = function(array, keyword) {
    return _.find(array, word => {
      return _.find(word.types, type => {
        if (type == keyword) return true;
      });
    });
  };

  let components = address.address_components;

  components.forEach(element => {
    if (findInArray(components, "street_number")) {
      newObj.plot_short = element.short_name;
      newObj.plot_long = element.long_name;
    }
  });

  return address;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Share your lodash code attempt, please.

Comment: *"Basically it should be based on what the type is."* please add some more examples.

Comment: what should happen with the first one and `address` part? what should happen with more types than one?

Comment: You should loop over the array, with something like `for(var i=0,individualObject,l=yourArray.length; i<l; i++){ individualObject = yourArray[i]; }`, then test for property values and use assignment to create something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object and assign long and short properties.

```js
var array = [{ long_name: "1144", short_name: "1144", types: ["street_address"] }, { long_name: "New York", short_name: "New York", types: ["city"] }, { long_name: "New York County", short_name: "New York County", types: ["admin_area", "portal"] }, { long_name: "New York", short_name: "NY", types: ["state"] }, { long_name: "United States", short_name: "US", types: ["country"] }],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(o =>
        Object.assign(...['long', 'short'].map(k => 
            ({ [k + '_' + o.types[0]]: o[k + '_name'] })))));
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: I dont understand one thing. Why the CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to programmatically loop over your keys and insert them into a new object. Hopefully this code snippet will help, although you'll have to think about having multiple items in your `types` array.

```js
var array = [
  { "long_name": "1144", "short_name": "1144", "types": ["street_address"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "New York", "types": ["city"] },
  { "long_name": "New York County", "short_name": "New York County", "types": ["admin_area", "portal"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "NY", "types": ["state"] },
  { "long_name": "United States", "short_name": "US", "types": ["country"] }
];
var newObj = {};

array.forEach((obj) => {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key === 'types') return;
    var type = obj.types[0];
    var lengthType = key.split('_')[0];
    var newKey = `${type}_${lengthType}`;

    newObj[newKey] = obj[key];
  }
});
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've loop input then continue loop `types` because `types` is Array, then build new object

```js
var input = [
  { "long_name": "1144", "short_name": "1144", "types": ["street_address"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "New York", "types": ["city"] },
  { "long_name": "New York County", "short_name": "New York County", "types": ["admin_area", "portal"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "NY", "types": ["state"] },
  { "long_name": "United States", "short_name": "US", "types": ["country"] }
];

var newObj = {};

_.each(input, (o) => {
    _.each(o.types, (type) => {
 _.mapKeys(o, (value, key) => {
     if (key !== "types") {
  _.assign(newObj, {[type.split("_")[0] + "_" + key.split("_")[0]]: value});
     }
        });
    });
});

console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to rename the keys, map over your current array, and for each object, output a new object with custom named keys :

```js
let input =[
  { "long_name": "1144", "short_name": "1144", "types": ["street_address"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "New York", "types": ["city"] },
  { "long_name": "New York County", "short_name": "New York County", "types": ["admin_area", "portal"] },
  { "long_name": "New York", "short_name": "NY", "types": ["state"] },
  { "long_name": "United States", "short_name": "US", "types": ["country"] }
]

let output = input.map( obj => {
 return {
    street_short : obj.long_name,
    street_long  : obj.short_name,
 }
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Yay, a silent downvote! Thanks, it had been a long time. Very constructive.